# transfering data from one cluster to another

Tags: scp, cluster

I would like to transfer my data from one cluster to another. for that, I know that I can write on the command line:

```
scp -r Folder1 myname@XXX.YY.WW.ZZ:/work/myname
```

However, I would like to submit a job (qsub) via a batch file. When I write the command line on the terminal, the password is asked. Is there any way to put the password in the batch file and automate the job ?

Comment: try `sshpass -p "password"  scp -r Folder1 myname@XXX.YY.WW.ZZ:/work/myname`

Comment: I should replace the "password" by the password of my account in XXX.YY.WW.ZZ, right ?

Comment: yes. That's right.

Comment: sshpass: command not found

Comment: `sudo apt install sshpass`

Comment: But I am in the cluster and it is not my computer to install things easily.

Comment: Hmm. I see. Does your cluster have `expect` installed?

Comment: No unfortunately.

Comment: Where is `Folder1` located?

Comment: where the batch file is. So, I don't need to give the complete address, right ?

Comment: yes. no need for complete address.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to generate a ssh key like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

on your host machine and copy the content of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and lastly add it to the remote machines `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

make sure remote machine have the permissions 0700 for `~./ssh folder` and 0600 for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

This way you won't need to enter password everytime.

**Reference:** [How to pass password to scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)

Comment: I actually started to do ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_scp.pub myname@XXX.YY.WW.ZZ but the transfer of key was not successful: I cannot find the key on the other host nor at home neither at ~/.ssh

Comment: Why not? how did you do it?

Comment: where the key should be located when you do ssh-copy-id -i  ?

Comment: I have not used `ssh-copy-id -i ` in my answer. Can't follow what you're trying to do.